# Laravel : Select from three tables using eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables

1. service_cats (id - cat_name)
2. service_sub_cats (id - cat_id - sub_cat_name)
3. sub_cat_contents (id - sub_cat_id - title - content)

and I made this relations

**serviceCat**

```
public function serviceSubCat()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('ServiceSubCat');
    }
```

**serviceSubCat**

```
public function ServicesCat()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('ServiceCat', 'cat_id');
    }

    public function ssContent()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('SubCatContent');
    }
```

**subCatContent**

```
public function ssCat()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('ServiceSubCat', 'sub_cat_id');
    }
```

I need to grape data from the three tables to use them.

**here is my controller**

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $serCat = ServiceCat::where('id', $id)->first();
        $getId = $serCat->sub_status;
        if ($getId == 1) {
            $subCats = ServiceSubCat::with('ssContent')->where('cat_id', $id)->get();
            //dd($subCats);
            return View::make('portal.services.servicesDetailsList', compact('serCat', 'subCats'));
        } else {
            return View::make('portal.services.servicesDetails');
        }
    }
```

now I get Error

> Column not found

I need to get the cat_name, sub_cat_name, title, content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your relations are defined as:

**serviceCat**

```
public function serviceSubCat()
{
    return $this->hasMany('ServiceSubCat', 'cat_id');
}
```

**serviceSubCat**

```
public function ServicesCat()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('ServiceCat', 'cat_id');
}

public function ssContent()
{
  return $this->hasMany('SubCatContent', 'sub_cat_id');
}
```

**subCatContent**

```
public function ssCat()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('ServiceSubCat', 'sub_cat_id');
}
```

**your controller**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $serCat = ServiceCat::where('id', $id)->with('serviceSubCat.ssContent')->first();
    $getId = $serCat->sub_status;
    if ($getId == 1) {
        return View::make('portal.services.servicesDetailsList', compact('serCat'));
    } else {
        return View::make('portal.services.servicesDetails');
    }
}
```

Then in your view you can do as:

```
{{ $serCat->cat_name }}
@foreach ($serCat->serviceSubCat as $ser)
    {{ $ser->sub_cat_name }}
    @foreach ($ser->ssContent as $subCatContent)
        {{ $subCatContent->title }}
        {{ $subCatContent->content }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for replay but got this error `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$title`

Comment: Try the updated answer. There was a missing `@foreach` in view's code.

Comment: yes this worked just find didn't think about making `foreach` under `foreach` thanks a lot @Amit